# how to add Custom column with link in sales order grid magento

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, order-grid, custom-column-grid

[image]I want to add **custom column** in **sales order grid**.

In the row data I want to add link using block render or using ui-component.

Comment: Check my ans on here. you will get idea about to add new column in sales order grid.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261204/add-phone-number-column-in-sales-order-grid/261207#261207

Comment: @AasimGoriya i am following your ans but i am not able to add <a> tag in column data.

Comment: Sorry my ans is for magento 2 not for m1

Comment: @AasimGoriya i need to convert this in m2 but still your ans is not useful.